# JAVA_HOME environment variable does not point to JDK or JRE

Tags: java, java-7, exe4j

I've got a problem when starting up java application (.exe) instead of .jar . FYI, I've got a procedure on the track such as installing java (JDK 7 & JRE 7), using environment variables JAVA_HOME & EXE4J_JAVA_HOME. But, when I take a look at control panel, Java(TM) 7 wasn't there. Here's the image that I get when I startup my .exe

[image]

when I click ok, this is the result

[image]

[image]

Very appreciate the others' help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this and post the result:

Go to: `Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables » System Variables`

Look for the JAVA_HOME and post the value of the variable. Next, go to file explorer and search for the path that you have copied from the JAVA_HOME variable.

Do you have the folder mentioned on the system varible here?

Answer (score 1):

To get a 64-bit executable, select the check box on "Executable info->32 bit or 64 bit" step of the exe4j wizard.

The fact that you see multiple error message windows is a bug and will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

What is your system specs. Is it 32 bit or 64 bit. check the JAVA installation which you have matches the system/OS specs.

There are 2 options. Either compile your java application with a 64 bit java compiler (which u already have) OR you can install a java 32 bit installation and set you JAVA_HOME to point to that64 bit java should take care of java apps compiled in 32-bit environment.

Comment: 64 bit, but according to image, it said that I should point to 32 bit. What should I do now?

Comment: I have done that way, but still get nothing. Just that error message that be showed to me. Could you suggest another idea, pals? Thank you

Comment: “*compile your java application with a 64 bit java compiler*” makes no sense. It doesn’t matter under which architecture you compile a Java application. The key point is exe4j which generates a 32 bit executable wrapping the already compiled Java application.